# Fix footer table/div issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to align three small logos in a footer widget in a single line (using Wordpress, theme is Press coders) I've created a mock up of what I want at:

[Image](http://reading-college.ac.uk/sites/default/files/image-idea.jpg)

However everything is skewing beyond belief!

You can see the mess in my footer at:

[www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk](http://oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk)

I've tried using both a div and a table, my latest table looks like:

```
<table align="right">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/gym/">
    <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/health-and-fitness-1.jpg" alt="Health and Fitness" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="/hair-and-beauty/>
    <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp- content/uploads/2014/07/hair-and-beauty-1.jpg" alt="Hair and Beauty" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by previous answers, your HTML syntax is wrong. However, using tables for that is not the correct approach. You can simply keep the links and images inline and text-align right.

It depends on the complexity of the layout, but display:inline-block may be needed or you might need to wrap certain elements in a container. Either approach is superior to using tables for layout ([Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html))

HTML

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></a><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></a><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></a>
```

CSS

```
body {
  text-align: right;
}

a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wuvoriye/1/edit

Comment: Hold your horses! I only want to align this footer widget text to the right not my entire websites copy! 

How can I modify the CSS above so that it only applies to this footer widget?

Comment: Reference a parent class or ID. Such as .footer-widget-area or something of that nature. So instead of "body" it would be ".footer-widget-area" or something of that nature. You will need to restructure the footer HTML a little when you remove the table, anyhow.

Comment: Thanks Jason, will give it a whirl, what do you mean by "restructure the footer html a little"?

Comment: Your footer is constructed using a table. If you remove the table, and use another method, that would be restructuring the HTML.

Comment: Gotcha, I tried replacing body with the following classes:
     
.footer-widget-container
.textwidget
.widget widget_text

Unfortunately I still have a picture of a kitten on the left hand side :/

Answer (score 2):

You html syntax is wrong. You are missing closing anchors and quotation marks. Try this.

```
<table align="right">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/gym/">
                <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/health-and-fitness-1.jpg" alt="Health and Fitness" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/hair-and-beauty/">
            <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp- content/uploads/2014/07/hair-and-beauty-1.jpg" alt="Hair and Beauty" /></a>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works but shrinks my images and aligns them to the left rather than the right. I guess some styling must be being pulled from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/z9KKn/)

```
<div class="logos">
  <a href="/gym/">
    <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/health-and-fitness-logo.jpg" alt="Health and Fitness" />
  </a>
  <a href="/hair-and-beauty/">
    <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/hair-and-beauty-logo.jpg" alt="Hair and Beauty" />
  </a>
  <a href="/nutrition-and-refreshment/">
    <img src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/nutrition-and-refreshment.jpg" alt="Nutrition and Refreshment" />
  </a>
</div>
```

---

```
.logos {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}
.logos img {
  height: 80%;
}
.logos a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

***Note:** For the best effects resize images to same size.

Comment: Unfortunately this still aligns the logos to the left :/

Comment: Your markup is wrong, put div `.logos` just before `</footer>` and it's gonna be ok ;)

Comment: I put the .logos in the stylesheet, is this incorrect?

Comment: No it's not incorrect, I don't talking about CSS. You must put `<div class="logos">` just before the `</footer>`

Comment: Thanks, I've just done so - it gives me a small trio of logos?

Comment: Sorry I looked again put div just before `</section>` and don't wrap it with another div.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so where to start:

1: dont use a table.
2: dont use a table.
3: you get the picture here....

Now for the fix: 
I have left comments into it for you so to explain what I did.
I put in inline style for you so just add it to your css file.

```
<section class="footer-widget-container">
    <div id="footer-widget-area" class="inside widget-area">
        <!-- Social Media Div First -->
        <div id="pc_info_widget_designfolio-pro-3" class="widget pc_info_widget" style="width: 40%; float: left;">
            <!-- simple p tag with a class is all that needed -->
            <p class="phone" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                (949) 867-5307
            </p>
            <!-- keep it simple: list items floated left + you can now just add as many as you want -->
            <ul style="float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <li style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                    <a class="sm-icon" target="_blank"  href="http://www.facebook.com//lifestyle-center">
                        <img width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/images/facebook.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                    <a class="sm-icon" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com//lifestylecentre">
                        <img width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/images/twitter.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Logo Div Second -->
        <div id="text-8" class="widget widget_text" style="width: 60%; float: left;">
            <div class="textwidget">
                <!-- Dont use tables unless its table data | Simple ul list itmes float left again -->
                <ul style="float: right;">
                    <li style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <a href="/gym/">
                            <img alt="Health and Fitness" src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/health-and-fitness-1.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <a href="/hair-and-beauty/">
                            <img alt="Hair and Beauty" src="http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/hair-and-beauty-1.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey dude, I put this in my footer widget, but it still looks very wrong!?

Comment: I see that.

on my screen its perfect like that. you must have other style sheets adding stuff in there.

Comment: .footer-widget-container { text-align: right;}
take that style out. Its pusing all text to the right.

Comment: it loos like you got it mate.

Comment: one last thing. Under your class="textwidget" logos.

make them into list items and float the li left. then add to the ul the following style: list-style: none. then just use padding on the li's to give them some room.

But it looks like you seem to have it

Comment: If you do it this way you can link to the sites.